# Use an iccube report for more than one schema

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

We would like to re-use an iccube report on different schemas. The idea is to have some kind of template that can be used on different schemas.

What are the solutions for doing this (we use ic3reporting.openReport to open a report) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the report schema parameter

```
ic3reporting.openReport({
  report:{
    name:"report_name",
    params:"{\"ic3schema\":\"schema_name\"}"
  }
)
```